Atomic commit for multiple async sessions?
I have some async sqlalchemy code for working with postgres.
Initially, the code looked like this:
async def f(session: AsyncSession):
    ...

async def g(session: AsyncSession):
    ....


await asyncio.gather(f(session), g(session))
await session.commit()

I got some error messages from sqlalchemy, indicating that AsyncSession is not safe to be used by multiple functions concurrently. So I rewrote my code like this:

await asyncio.gather(f(session_1), g(session_2))
await session_1.commit()
await session_2.commit()

But it's possible for session_1.commit() to succeed and session_2.commit() to fail, leaving the database in an invalid state.
Is there a proper way to work with multiple async connections to postgres, and rollback all the changes in case an error occurs?

Are there alternative packages to sqlalchemy that would make this easier?

I don't think it was meant to do that but maybe I don't understand the use case.  Can you give more details about the tasks?  Are they short tasks or computationally intensive?  Are they all writing?
